# Change Actionbar Menu Font and Background color

Tags: android, user-interface

Hey I would like to know how to change the font family and the background color of the ActionBar menu items .
I have applied the same to a Navigation View , but i'm unable to do it for the Menu Item on the ActionBar.
Given below is the **Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

            <item
                android:id="@+id/local_english"
                android:title="@string/english" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/local_french"
                android:title="@string/french" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/local_german"
                android:title="@string/german" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

And example of achieving it in the NavigationView is also provided.
Given Below are the styles and the Activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nv"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Style_Menu"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="#808080"
        app:itemIconTint="#808080"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

**Style_menu**

```
<style name="Style_Menu">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/sans_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_configuration_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Themes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_themes"
        android:title="@string/Themes"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/DarkMode"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_darkmode"
        android:title="@string/darkmode" />

</menu>
```

Comment: You have to use the predefined name instead of your own, and if you are custom defining it then in that case include it in the styles.xml